# Obtain CodeIgniter links that consider routes.php

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How can I link pages in my site considering routes.php?

Example:

```
$route['login'] = 'user/login';
```

The code above allows me to see "user/login" visiting just "login". But how can I link to that page using the internal route (user/login) and get as a result the "external route" "login".

I think it's important because I could change my URLs just modifiying "routes.php" and linking everything with internal routes.

From a Drupal perspective I can have my internal route "node/1" and the external url could be "about-us". So if I use "l('node/1')" this will return "about-us". Is there a function like "drupal_get_path_alias"?

Right now I can't find anything in the CI docs that point me to the right direction.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at using something like

http://osvaldas.info/smart-database-driven-routing-in-codeigniter

This would allow you to have the routes configured in the database. Then if you want to dynamically create you links through a model like this:

```
class AppRoutesModel extends CI_Model
{
    public function getUrl($controller)
    {
        $this->db->select('slug');
        $this->db->from('app_routes');
        $this->db->where('controller', $controller);

        $query = $this->db->result();
        $data = $query->row();

        $this->load->library('url');

        return base_url($data->slug);
    }

    public function getController($slug)
    {
        $this->db->select('controller');
        $this->db->from('app_routes');
        $this->db->where('slug', $slug);

        $query = $this->db->result();
        $data = $query->row();

        return $data->controller;
    }
}
```

These have not been fully tested but will hopefully give you the general idea.

I hope this helps you :)

Edit------------------------------

You can create a routes_helper.php and add a function like

```
//application/helpers/routes_helper.php
function get_route($path)
{
    require __DIR__ . '/../config/routes.php';

    foreach ($route as $key => $controller) {
        if ($path == $controller) {
            return $key;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$this->load->helper('routes');

echo get_route('controller/method');
```

This does roughly what you want although this method does not support the $1 $2 etc vars that can be added to reflect the :num or :any wildcard that exist. You can edit the function to add that functionality but this will point you in the right direction :D

Comment: The solution you point does the same as routes.php but instead of using a file it uses a table. It's cool but it's not what I want. In routes.php you instruct CI what to serve if a specific path pattern is reached, but there's no way to know the desired path when linking an internal route. Thanks anyway @mic.

Comment: see my new changes I think I understand now

Comment: Ok, now your code looks like a good starting point. It needs a little love to make the parameters work also... But you point the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem glad I could help 

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect 301 /user/login http://www.example.com/login
```

Comment: Thanks but an .htaccess file with redirect 301 wont change the link. It will do just a redirection... Moreover it would be 2 files to edit and keep synchronized.